# How to use Tensorflow lite with java?

Tags: gradle, aar, tensorflow-lite

We have an app written in JavaFX (Java 8) that we deploy to users using macOS and Windows. 
We have a model in Tensorflow lite (.tflite) and it seems as if Tensorflow lite does provide a Java API. However, when I add `compile group: 'org.tensorflow', name: 'tensorflow-lite', version: '1.10.0'` I can't use it in the project, I just get `package org.tensorflow.lite does not exist`.

Since tf lite comes as an AAR package, do I have to change something in my gradle to make that work, or does tf lite really only run on Android?

Comment: maybe use maven

Comment: any luck???, i am also trying to create javafx application for jetson nano

Comment: No, we ended up using ONNX runtime which works fine with Java